# How to achieve Infinite scroll in React with React Query?

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-query

I want my API to fetch new data as in increase the page number when I have reached the bottom of the page, basically I want to infinite scroll with React Query.

I have literally watched all the videos out there but am still unable to figure out why isn't it working. Please help me out.

```
events: (30) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
hasNextPage: true
```

There's no mention of the number of pages available in this API, or the total number of events available. The only way to check if there is a next page is through this `hasNextPage: true` property which returns either `true` or `false`

So I have no clue on how to do that using React-Query, I have tried multiple approaches. Can anyone please help me out on how to achieve Infinite scroll using React-Query with this data from the API.

Comment: If hasNextPage is true, load more data, if hadNextPage is false, stop loading data

Comment: I did that, and my component is re-rendering multiple times as I reach the bottom of the page by calling multiple API calls at once instead of just one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the npm package [react-infinite-scroll-component](https://www.js-howto.com/react-query-how-to-test-infinite-query-with-jest-and-react-testing-library/) along with [useInfiniteQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useInfiniteQuery) hook.

[This article](https://www.js-howto.com/react-query-how-to-test-infinite-query-with-jest-and-react-testing-library/) demonstrates it in detail.

Answer (score 3):

### useInfiniteQuery

**If your API response data doesn't have any page info**, you can use the second parameter returned from `getNextPageParam` to achieve your needs. This parameter returns an array containing all the fetched page content, so you can use its `length` as a basis.

### Sample code:

```js
  const {
    data, isLoading, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage,
  } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['someKey'],
    queryFn: fetchData,
    // here
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage, pages) => pages.length + 1,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have work with `useInfiniteQuery` and `hasNextPage` would be enough.

Query:

```
const { isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, data } = useInfiniteQuery(
    ['some-key' ,page, size],
    ({ pageParam = 0 }) => getList({ page: pageParam, ...params }),
    {
       getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => (!lastPage.last ? lastPage.number + 1 : undefined),
    },
);

const inViewport = useInViewport(ref);

useEffect(() => {
    if (inViewport) fetchNextPage();
}, [inViewport]);
```

And your list would be like this:

```
<div>
  {data?.pages.map((page) => (
     <React.Fragment key={page.number}>
        {page.events.map(renderItem)} 
     </React.Fragment>
  ))}
  {hasMore && (
    <div className={styles.loading} ref={ref}>
      {isFetchingNextPage && <Spinner/>}
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Since the API doesn't has any parameters, so I need to change the page numbers by creating a state `const[page, setPage] = useState(0)` and then changing it in the `getNextPageParam` by checking if `hasNextPage: true` then increase the page number in the state otherwise return undefined. And because of this, the component is re-rendering multiple times. This is how my API url looks like - `https://allsportsapi2.p.rapidapi.com/api/cricket/team/${params?.id}/matches/previous/${page}`

Comment: Also, `lastPage.number` returns undefined, since there is no property as number.

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox from your code?

Comment: Yeah, sure. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-cookies-j3iupe?file=/src/Pages.js) I haven't really used sandbox before, so sorry if I missed anything.

Comment: This doesn't work , get a sample of the API response.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using the component PerfectScrollbar from this package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-perfect-scrollbar

and by using the prop onYReachEnd you can call a function that first check if hasNextPage is true then you will need to check that you are not fetching data currently in order to not fetch all pages at same time, you can do that by check that by checking loadingGetData is false